# How to give reference at the end of particular page?

Tags: footnotes

[image]

Hello friends, 
I want to give reference at the end of particular page in which reference is mentioned just like attached image. Please write the latex code , Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do mean an actual bibliographic reference, and that you're using `biblatex`? If yes, then you're probably after `\footcite{<citation-key>}` I think. For general text at end of page, that's a `\footnote{text}`.

Comment: So `\footnote{Poseidon was initially ...}` then.